# What is a CMS with good user forums support?

Tags: cms, forum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

If I'm starting from scratch with any CMS I want, which one has good support (or a plugin) for discussion forums?

Comment: In my experience, Joomla! is a no no!

Answer (score 2):

The obvious choice is Drupal.  Very popular and tons of plugins.  It has a good integrated forum.  Because of this, though, there aren't a lot of options for alternative forum softwares.

However, while it's not a true CMS, Wordpress can be very powerful as a CMS web site and has tons of plugins, including forum plugins.
http://chasesagum.com/5-best-choices-for-wordpress-forum-plugins

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress has a large library of plugins and there are scripts out there to allow intergration with the major forums including PHPBB, Invision and VBulletin.

Comment: Update: check out bbpress, a wordpress forum plugin: http://www.bbpress.org

Answer (score 1):

[PHPbb](http://www.phpbb.com/) has a good support community and has a lot of MOD's.  if you can't find the plugins you want,  you can easily request on the community forum so many developers will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The [Vanillaforum](http://vanillaforums.org/) is a great opensource forum that now has a feature that is supposed to let you embed it in sites. It says it is working with Drupal and Wordpress. http://vanillaforums.org/addon/embedvanilla-plugin